# android coverflow view

Tags: android, coverflow

Hi i am developing application in android.In that i displayed some images in coverflow view that was working fine.Below that cover flow view i need to display some data in list view.I am new to android and i don't know how to display the  listview below the coverflow view.please help me,here my code:

```
My XML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.coverflow.Coverflow
        android:id="@+id/cover_flow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


   <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  


</LinearLayout>

My Activity class:


public class NewspaperCoverFlowActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListViewwithimageAdapter listadapter;
    ListView list;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        Coverflow coverFlow;
        coverFlow = new Coverflow(this);

        coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter =  new ImageAdapter(this);

        coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);          

        coverFlow.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

        coverFlow.setSpacing(2);
        coverFlow.setSelection(1, true);
        coverFlow.setAnimationDuration(1500);   
//        setContentView(coverFlow);
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listadapter = new ListViewwithimageAdapter(this);
        list.setAdapter(listadapter);



    }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a LinearLayout with the orientation set to vertical and set that as your content view. Then add the Cover flow view and the list view to the layout.

If you do it in a layout xml it would be something like this (change the "com.example.package" to the pckage where your CoverFlow is located):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.package.CoverFlow
        android:id="@+id/cover_flow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Anders. In XML fine i can able to create list view.But cover flow view i can't.HOw to create coverflow view in XML file

Comment: Edited my answer with xml example.

Comment: Thanks Anders.One more thing i can't able to access the coverflow view in my activity class.For example in my xml i have listview i can do like"ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.layout.main);" in my activity class. same thing i tried in cover flow but its saying no such properties.please help me.

Comment: Hi Anders,now list view only displaying in my screen. The cover flow view is not displaying.I have edited my question please check.

Comment: To access the coverflow view just use: Coverflow coverflow = (Coverflow)findViewById(R.id.cover_flow);

Comment: How to create the ListViewwithimageAdapter?please post the code.